# Vapor 3 Websocket with Sessions

Tags: websocket, vapor

In Vapor 2 it was possible to access a session when connecting a new websocket.

For example:

```
setupRoutes(){

  socket("ws") { request, websocket in
    let session = try request.assertSession()
    guard let userId = session.data["user_id"]?.string else {
      ..
    }
}
```

In Vapor 3 configure.swift:

```
let wss = NIOWebSocketServer.default()
  wss.get("ws") { websocket, request in

    --get session information--

    websocket.onText { websocket, text in
      websocket.send(text)
    }
 }
 services.register(wss, as: WebSocketServer.self)
```

With Vapor 3 the SessionMiddleware will not be invoked before passing the HTTP upgrade request to the WebsocketServer.
So how can I access session information?

Comment: Hey you could take a look at my WS lib for Vapor3 as it may solve your problem https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/WS and also there are example backend app https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/AlexoChat and iOS client app https://github.com/emvakar/Chat_client

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm super aware that this thread is old and the OP probably found an answer or gave up months ago. Just in case anyone comes across this still looking, can't you use `websocket.session` to access the session?

This would make the Vapor 3 code

```
let wss = NIOWebSocketServer.default()
  wss.get("ws") { websocket, request in

    guard let userID = (try? websocket.session).data["user_id"]?.string else {
        ...
    }

    websocket.onText { websocket, text in
      websocket.send(text)
    }
 }
 services.register(wss, as: WebSocketServer.self)
```

Comment: You know how to set web socket.session.data from iOS app? Just a simple example using URLSessionWebSocketTask?